# how do i undo a split() method or like reverse split()

Tags: java

```
In this text file we will replace the word text with another word
But the number of times the text value is repeated depends on the user input
```

I have this text written exactly as is inside a text document (its of two rows). I want to know how to replace specific word depends on the user input.

For example the user wants to replace word "the" which is repeated 4 times in the text document up with a new word = java, how its possible to replace all the "the"(s) ?

the result would be

```
In this text file we will replace java word text with another word
But java number of times java text value is repeated depends on java user input
```

I'd post my code but its unfinished yet, so if I posted it you'll probably say stuff not related to the topic

Thanks in advance

edit: i have initialized `String[] columns` and `String Line;` also i've wrote `Line = scan.nextLine();` and `columns = Line.split(" ");`

thats to compare the user's input with the column[i]

Comment: your actuall question is totally different than your question title... Also [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not related to your heading, where you talk of split(), in your post only about replace(). Also nothing of undo.

Comment: Just use the `replace` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String source = "In this text file we will replace the word text with another word But the number of times the text value is repeated depends on the user input";

String result = source.replace("the", "java");
```

Comment: he´s not using any kind of regex, so i think, to avoid any kind of possibility to create bugs here, a simple `String#replace` should be enough

Comment: but i wanna use the FileReader and FileWriter will it work with the replace? because our teacher didnt explain the replace method

Comment: @Kevin Esche Correct, the replace method should be sufficient and more performant.

Comment: @Sec Karma You have to read the text of the file, then use replace and then write the text back to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceAll()`-method.